# search a value in all column of all tables of db2 database

Tags: db2, db2-400

I want to search a value in all column of all tables in my database. I have done it before in SQL but I don't know how I can do this in db2.

Comment: How have you done this in other SQL dialects? If you can provide an SQL statement, and the dialect it is using, then maybe someone can help translate it to DB2.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good (free) SQL tool [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) which has this functionality